# Convert Array to Object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to convert array to objects .

```
let arr = ["value1","value2"]
```

My trying code is :

```
 Object.assign({},arr)
```

expected Output  :

```
  {value1:{},value2:{} }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) and map the wanted keys with empty objects.

```js
let keys = ["value1", "value2"],
    object = Object.fromEntries(keys.map(key => [key, {}]));

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try with [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) as the following:

```js
const arr = ["value1", "value2"];
const result = {};

arr.forEach(e => result[e] = {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use array reduce!

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

```
arr.reduce((accumulator, value) => ({ ...accumulator, [value]: {} }), {});
```

Comment: Or: ``` arr.reduce((accumulator, value) => Object.assign(({ [value]: {} }, accumulator)))```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to get the desired output:

```js
const data = ["value1", "value2"];

const result = data.reduce((r, k) => (r[k] = {}, r), {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's also `Object.fromEntries` method specifically designed to convert an array of entries (key-value tuples) to an Object.

```js
let arr = ['value1', 'value2'];
let entries = arr.map(el => [el, {}]);
let obj = Object.fromEntries(entries);

console.log(obj);
```